# Searching for a specific string of text, then replacing the string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PHP file with content similar to this:

```
<table class="select_descript" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" valign="middle"><tbody><tr><td>Top songs for the past week. Updated Saturday, 21 March 2015</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I have the date in there, I want to be able to replace this date section only in this PHP file with the current date. I'm thinking of making use of finding both `valign="middle"><tbody><tr><td>` and the word `Updated` and use a -replace method.

```
$phpfile = phpfile.php
(Get-Content $phpfile) -replace "(?<=Updated ).+","Updated (Get-Date).ToLongDateString()"
```

But I am stuck with the expression.

Comment: Not really, has to be more automatic, there's multiple PHP files, with slightly different dates,  however they all have the same code and same word "Updated“ in the same position. Why I thought of an expression to target that area if the PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say under what circumstances the file is being changed.  My first suggestion is to create a source template file with a unique token where the current date goes.

```
...<td>Top songs for the past week. Updated [[DATE_HERE]]</td>...
```

Then the replacement is straightforward and mostly foolproof.

```
(gc template.php) -replace '[[DATE_HERE]]',(Get-Date).ToLongDateString() | sc $phpfile
```

For the regex solution, you need the string that identifies the location but is least likely to change. I wouldn't try to parse based on the HTML tags, or a change in formatting will break your regex.  In your example I would use the whole "Top songs ..." text.

```
$searchText = 'Top songs for the past week. Updated [^<]*'
$replaceText = "Top songs for the past week. Updated $((Get-Date).TolongDateString())"

(Get-Content $phpfile -Raw) -replace $searchText,$replaceText | Set-Content $phpfile
```

Note that the `-Raw` parameter to `Get-Content` causes it to read the whole file at once and then close the file so that you don't get an error when you pass the same filename to Set-Content.

Comment: Yep, that works, the last code you have shared with the **$searchtext** and **$repacetext** - thank you